# Subtotaling cost data from another worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

For starters, I am fairly new to coding in VBA. I have a background with C++, MATLAB and some (very little) JAVA programming.

I have a large excel report with various projects with costs and managers associated with each. Each project has many rows of cost data. I need to create a program to walk through the report and subtotal all the costs allocated with a single project and create a row on another worksheet with the project manager, Project name and the subtotal value of the costs. Then, I need the program to move to the next project of a different name in the report and repeat until all unique projects have been subtotaled on the 2nd worksheet.

I hope I described the situation well enough for anyone to understand and help...

Thanks!!

Comment: Sounds like quite a project... You'd best get started...

Comment: Seriously though, in the nicest possible way this site is for people dealing with specific problems in their code.  If you go away, write some code and can't work out why somethings not working we'll be happy to help

Comment: Have a look at the `SUBTOTAL` function in Excel formulas if you're on Excel 2010 +

Comment: Tom Preston, Sorry, I know it came off as I was trying to have someone else do everything for me but I have been spinning my wheels for the past 2 days and couldn't get any traction on the task. I was just looking for a nudge in the right direction and wasn't finding anyone explaining how to work with data in the way I needed to. I need to look at a project name and create an array of all the costs associated with rows that match that project name and subtotal it. from there I believe I could figure out the rest (hopefully). Have a great day!

Comment: @J.Wynn ok, to give you a nudge, when you need to apply the same process to multiple things you need a loop, so you'll need a loop for all the projects (probably laid out in worksheets).  Inside the loop you'll need to run some commands (counts/sums by the sounds of it), and print these values to the report sheet.  Address the commands first, then when this works for one sheet, add the loop.  This is a great reading resource: http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/MainPage.aspx  Good luck, come back if you get stuck

Answer (score 1):

***This isn't an answer per say but I think what I am going to say will take more characters than a comments will allow***

The key concepts you need to use to get to this point:

Sorting the worksheet. This might be a fun task and no sure if covered (in SO documentation that is). A quick google search will find you tons of examples. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840646.aspx

Looping through ranges in a worksheets. Covered sufficiently in the documentation

Referencing cell values so you can do comparisons (project to project etc). If you're used to lite programming already assigning variable values should be pretty easy.

Learning how to place values in a new location using the Offset property. Also, covered in the documentation.

This should be plenty for you to get started and come back once you have a specific question with code you've already tried.

Comment: @Ralph I am guessing someone doesnt like my post? LOL I prefaced my post by saying it wasnt an answer and I thought it was at least worth pointing someone in the right direction. I wouldve made it a comment had space allowed.

Comment: Oh i see typos. I guess i should make more taipos going 4ward and tg @MatsMug lol